# How to read the implementation class in default interface method?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations

I want to create a default interface method that can respond with the annotated value of the implementation class.

Example: in the following, I want all Child implementations to read their own `@Generated` value field:

```
public interface Parent {
    default String[] find() {
        return AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(this.getClass(), Generated.class).value();
    }
}

@Generated(value = {"test"})
public class Child implements Parent {

}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(new Child().find());
```

Result: `NullPointerException`, because the call tries to find the annotation on the `Parent` interface class, not the implementation class.

It it still possible somehow?

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise. [`this.getClass()` does not return Parent](https://ideone.com/FMcRYr)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on a false premise. [`this.getClass()` does not return Parent](https://ideone.com/FMcRYr)

Assuming your `@Generated` annotation is the [javax version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Generated.html), you are getting a NPE because it is not retained at runtime.

See [@Retention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html)